# How to make if/else statements read first matching keywords? (Java)

Tags: java, if-statement

How do you implement a condition for the first matching keyword in a ChatBot program? The code below is current code i'm using:

```
public static void firstMatchingKeyword1() {
    String sex;
    sex = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Are you a guy or woman?");
            if (sex.contains("guy")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I am a guy too");  
            } else if (sex.contains("woman")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I am a woman too");
    }
}
```

The problem is that if both keywords are presents, I want the output to be the first keyword typed.
For example : If user typed "I am a woman but also a man". I want the output to be only the message "I am a woman too" instead of going through all the if statements one by one.

Comment: Personally I did not get your question to be honest :) But I am also not the one who has down voted your question :D

Answer (score 2):

[`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)) is your friend here.

> Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified substring, starting at the specified index.

```
if (sex.indexOf("guy") > 0 && sex.contains("guy") && (sex.indexOf("guy")<sex.indexOf("woman") || 
 sex.indexOf("woman") == -1)) {

{
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I am a guy too");  
} else if (sex.contains("woman")) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I am a woman too");
}
```

Comment: If the string contains 'guy' and not 'woman', this won't print anything.

Comment: @Michael Should be okay now.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you only need to add:

```
if (sex.contains("guy") && (sex.indexOf("guy")<sex.indexOf("woman") || sex.indexOf("woman") == -1)) {
```

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ You are rigth :) and there must be another check:
|| sex.indexOf("woman") == -1

Comment: Yeah. Missing another condition but that's okay. OP should pickup from there. That's it. Have an upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`indexOf(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-) for this. This function:

> Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the
>   specified substring.

```
int posGuy   = sex.indexOf("guy");
int posWoman = sex.indexOf("woman");

if (posGuy >= 0 && posWoman >= 0) {
    if (posGuy < posWoman) {
        //guy before woman
    }
    else {
        //woman before guy
    }
}
else if (posGuy >= 0) {
    // guy
}
else if (posWoman >= 0) {
    // woman
}
```

It's worth noting that this is a case-sensitive search, so you may want to convert the input to lowercase before you search so that it matches "Guy", "GUY", "GuY" etc.